# how i do perform click event using c# in webBrowser

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, invokemember

How I do perform click event using c# in webBrowser.

This command is not working in c#, I don't know why.

```
webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("document.getElementsByName(\\"submitAddressButton\\")[0].click()");
```

But,
When I tried in web console. seem that command is work.

```
document.getElementsByName("submitAddressButton")[0].click();
```

I use getElementByName in c#, because there is no ID in HTML element target.

Below is fragmented of HTML :

```
    <form name="addressSelectForm" action="/online_customers/page/manageaddress/site_qualification/
6d5b51984c1b4a73aaf722f01474a256/select_address?submitToken=0980629f4dd64f1d9e72b05e16281d9b" method="post">

<span style="display:none">LOCXXXXX51</span><input type="submit" class="link-button" name="submitAddressButton" 
value="LOCXXXXX51">
<input type="hidden" name="fsaId" value="">

</form>
```

Thank
Jigu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
HtmlElementCollection d0cument = homeBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button");
            foreach (HtmlElement link in d0cument)
            {

                String class2 = link.InnerText;
                if (class2 == "Login")
                {
                    link.InvokeMember("click");
                    logincheck.Enabled = true;
                }
            }
```

i use like this because homeBrowser is have a lot of button